# What does the visible window in Windows refer to?

Tags: windows, winapi, rust

I checked all visible windows using `EnumWindows` and `IsWindowVisible`, and most of them are indeed visible to me, but there are two exceptions, `The Windows Input Experience` and `Program Manager`.

Although they are in the returned list, I cannot see them. So what does the visible window in Windows refer to?

Here is the simple code that I am using.

```rust
use windows_sys::{Win32::Foundation::*, Win32::UI::WindowsAndMessaging::*};

fn main() {
    unsafe extern "system" fn callback(hwnd: HWND, _: LPARAM) -> BOOL {
        if IsWindowVisible(hwnd) == FALSE {
            return TRUE;
        }

        let mut buf = [0u16; 1024];
        let len = GetWindowTextW(hwnd, buf.as_mut_ptr(), buf.len() as i32);
        if len > 0 {
            let title = String::from_utf16_lossy(&buf[..len as usize]);
            println!("title: {}", title);
        }
        TRUE
    }

    unsafe {
        EnumWindows(Some(callback), 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: A visible window is a window that has the [`WS_VISIBLE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-styles) window style set. The window with title *"Program Manager"* is the desktop window. Unless there's something funky going on in your system, that window is visible, and it's unclear why you'd expect it not to be. I don't know what *"The Window Input Experience"* window is.

Comment: @IInspectable Oh oh~, is the "program manager" the desktop window itself? I seem to understand a little bit, "The Window Input Experience" is a feature on win11 that I can see in the task manager, but I'm not sure which window it belongs to. Thank you very much, I have a rough idea of the direction now. Perhaps "The Window Input Experience" is a window that I can see but haven't realized yet.

Comment: There used to be a time when when the `WS_VISIBLE` style implied that a window was visible to the eye. Windows 2000 introduced layered windows with the ability to create translucent or fully transparent windows, breaking this strict correlation. Judging by the window name the *"Input Experience"* window is likely transparent, covering part or all of the desktop. And yes, the desktop is implemented as a regular window.

Comment: @IInspectable Thank you, this is truly a confusing layered style.

Comment: @IInspectable "Input Experience" is the touch keyboard, by the way.

Comment: Just because a window is "visible" to the OS doesn't always mean it is "visible" to a user.  Plenty of apps create "hidden" windows that are actually visible, they are either just too small to see or they are positioned off-screen.

Comment: There is no so-called visibility in Windows but in [IsWindowVisible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-iswindowvisible#remarks) which is used in your code. Also see [ScreenCaptureforHWND](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows.UI.Composition-Win32-Samples/blob/ee50e2ea137dcef7b82ba504eff7435e5ebf5294/cpp/ScreenCaptureforHWND/ScreenCaptureforHWND/Win32WindowEnumeration.h#L90). As far as `IsWindowVisible` is concerned, *The visibility state of a window is indicated by the `WS_VISIBLE` style bit*.

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT In my test, `IsWindowVisible` produces the same result as `let style = GetWindowLongW(hwnd, GWL_STYLE); let is_visible = style as u32 & WS_VISIBLE == 0;`, perhaps they are equivalent?

Comment: @tony Yes, they are equivalent in the view of documentation, unknown for the code.